# How to remove a row which doesnt contain numbers from a column, and how to convert a string with numbers to integers?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with 2 columns. One is description and the other one is amounts. Each row in the amounts column has numbers, but they are formated as strings with "" and some are non numerics. So two questions, how do I remove the non numeric strings? And also how do I convert the strings to integer?

```
data = {
    'Description': ["Fab", "Jay", "John", "Claud"],
    'Amount': ['12345', '7875.0', 'hdbsgd 3hdb4 dbd6', '7373.2']
    }
```

The real DataFrame is much larger than this one, so the solution needs to work for any number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
data = {'Description': ["Fab", "Jay", "John", "Claud"], 'Amount': ['12345', '7875.0', 'hdbsgd 3hdb4 dbd6', '7373.2']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['Amount'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Amount'], errors='coerce')
df = df.dropna()
df['Amount'] = df['Amount'].astype(int)
print(df)
```

output:

```
  Description  Amount
0         Fab   12345
1         Jay    7875
3       Claud    7373
```